# Excel VBA: Extract variable number of rows per variable number of phone numbers

Tags: excel, vba, field, rows, criteria

We are looking to automate this process using Excel VBA/macros because we process two to ten spreadsheets a week.
We want to extract a certain number of rows per a variable set of phone numbers.
For example: a spreadsheet with 200,000 rows has 20,000 rows assigned to ten phone numbers. We want to extract the first ten rows per phone number. Our resulting file will have 100 rows ordered by phone number.

Notes:

- We need to extract a variable number of records per phone number.
- The number of columns can vary.
- The number of rows can vary.
- We need the entire row of data.
- The phone number column may be in a different place in each spreadsheet.
- The number of phone numbers may vary.

Here's a code that works on one file, but cannot be duplicated to another worksheet because the "field", "criteria" and "rows" change per worksheet.

We thought IndexMatch might work, but it only returns one item, rather than duplicates.

We don't have a VBA solution, so we do this manually.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub ExtractPh()

' Establish filter
' Choose first unique phone number

    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:= _
        "800-836-9207"

' Copy ten non-sequential rows from row 1 to row 82

   Rows("1:82").Select

    Selection.Copy

' Add rows to second sheet

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Rows("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

' Move second to sheet to first position to save as separate file

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

' Return to main data sheet

    Sheets("Test LKY job").Select

' Choose second unique phone number in column

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:= _
        "800-907-3803"


' Choose second set of ten non-sequential rows and paste to first sheet

    Rows("6:26").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("12:12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

' Return to main data sheet

    Sheets("Test LKY job").Select

' Choose third unique phone number in column

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:= _
        "800-538-1668"

' Choose third set of non-sequential rows and paste to first sheet

    Rows("4:48").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("22:22").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code showing how you can filter a sheet, grab a specific number of visible rows, then copy those rows to another sheet.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set rngDest = Sheet2.Range("A2")

    Set rng = GetFirstVisibleRows(ActiveSheet, 1, "A", 10)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Copy rngDest
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(rng.Cells.Count, 0)
    End If

End Sub

'filter the data on a sheet by a given value in a given column, then
'   return a range with the first x visible rows
Function GetFirstVisibleRows(sht As Worksheet, filterColumn As Long, _
                            filterValue, howManyRows As Long) As Range

    Dim c As Range, rngVis As Range, rngCopy As Range

    'filter the sheet and find the remaining visible rows (if any)
    With sht.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:=filterValue
        On Error Resume Next '<< ignore error if no visible cells
        'offset/resize is to ignore the header row...
        Set rngVis = .Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Columns(1).Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0 '<< stop ignoring errors
    End With

    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
        'some visible (not filtered out) rows, so collect the first x of those...
        For Each c In rngVis.Cells
            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = c
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Application.Union(c, rngCopy)
            End If
            'exit loop if we have enough rows
            If rngCopy.Cells.Count >= howManyRows Then Exit For
        Next c
    End If

    Set GetFirstVisibleRows = rngCopy
End Function
```